# npm install aerospike does not work with Apple M1 chip

Tags: npm, aerospike

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for aerospike@3.16.6: wanted {"os":"linux,darwin,win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"})

npm ERR! notsup Valid OS: linux,darwin,win32

npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch: x64

npm ERR! notsup Actual OS: darwin

npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: arm64

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - Aerospike does not support the M1 architecture.

Becouse of this we can not upgrade our macs at work.

You could try to run it with [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861) installed.